# Windows 10 Permissions - You do not have permission to perform this task

Tags: windows-10, permissions

This is kind of a small problem. I want to add a custom screensaver to my computer but when i go to add the file into the folder i get the; "You do not have permission to perform this task" error what do i do?

Path: C: >Windows >System32

i know this is a windows file folder but i should still have permission to add a file to it. Right?

Comment: To add a file one time, log in with an admin userid, use Windows Explorer to copy the file to its destination. Then it will challenge you and you should be able to “continue” .

Answer (score 0):

You need to get administrative permissions to copy a file to C:\Windows\System32 directory. So login as Administrator account, or without logging off and back in, launch Command Prompt with administrative credentials, then run the command `copy "Filepath" C:\Windows\System32\`.